# Twig 1.24 don't have dump function

Tags: php, twig

I need the dump function to be able to troubleshoot a template. I see that dump function is available in 1.5, I have 1.24

When I print the twig version with

```
The current version is {{ constant('Twig_Environment::VERSION') }}
```

I get 1.24.0. But when I use the dump function:

```
{{ dump() }}
```

I get a Slim Application Error:

```
Type: Twig_Error_Syntax
Message: Unknown "dump" function in "template.html.twig" at line 15.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `1.24` matches `>=1.5` constraint, if you want exactly that version try `=1.5`

Comment: I want any version higher than 1.5, but I still get 1.24 I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes my bad, 1.24 and not 1.2.4... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add debug extension to your twig environment [manually](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

Comment: To me it only worked after I also added the: 
**$twig->enableDebug();**
 after doing what @arhey proposed above.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the 1.5 version is older than 1.24 (24 greater than 5). The 1.24 version is the latest stable one and the `dump` function is supported by it

Comment: I still get `dump unknown function`. When I print twig version with `{{ constant('Twig_Environment::VERSION') }}` I get 1.24.0

Comment: Maybe you did not activated the debug extension? See the documentation part: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html, a block that starts with `The dump function is not available by default`